# Jenkins Gradle Plugin is not installing

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Some of the Jenkins plugins are not installing on my ubuntu after choosing to install suggested plugins the first time of launch Jenkins.
[image: selected plugins]

Comment: What Jenkins version? Only recommended plugins?

Answer (score 0):

you can always download plugins in jenkins manually. In the UI go to Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins> search needed plugin and install . make sure you are also downloading all the dependencies to make the plugin working fine.